# Event Hub receiver does not read all messages

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I implemented 2 simple services in Service Fabric, which communicate over Event Hub and I encounter very strange behavior.

The listener service reads the messages using `PartitionReciever` with `ReceiveAsync` method. It reads the messages always from the start of the partition, but even though the `maxMessageCount` parameter is set to very high number, which definitely exceeds the number of messages in the partition, it reads only "random" amount of messages but never the full list. It always starts to read correctly from the beginning of the partition but it almost never reads the full list of messages which should be present there...

Did I miss something in documentation and this is normal behavior, or am I right, that this is very strange bahviour?

A code snippet of my receiver service:

```
PartitionReceiver receiver = eventHubClient.CreateReceiver(PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName, Convert.ToString(partition), PartitionReceiver.StartOfStream);

ServiceEventSource.Current.Write("RecieveStart");
IEnumerable<EventData> ehEvents = null;
int i = 0;
do
{
    try
    {
        ehEvents = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(1000);
        break;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {    
        if (i == NUM_OF_RETRIES-1)
        {
            await eventHubClient.CloseAsync();
            StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
    i++;
} while (i < NUM_OF_RETRIES);
```

Comment: Have you tried running your service at your local side? Will that work fine? In addition, are there other services which monitor the same messages? It will cause that some message are received by one service and some messages are received by the other one.

Comment: Hmm I just tried this morning to actually deploy it into SF Cluster in Azure and there it works correctly. The described behavior is on the local development cluster...
Is it possible that there is some timeout for retrieving messages and because of that only some messages are retrieved?
No there is no other service which would read from the Event Hub...